# CheckButton Status check in Toplevel

Tags: python, html, tkinter

I'm testing the Checkbutton widget on a TopLevel.
I was inspired by this in a main frame
[enter link description here](https://www.delftstack.com/fr/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-checkbutton/)

my test on a Toplevel initializes the Checkbutton widget with the square filled entirely in blue when it should be empty.

the goal is to capture the state of the widget according to the user's choice.
I don't want to use a class

here code of Seput.py

```
# coding:utf-8
#version 3.x python

# ==================================================
#                                         ID python
# ==================================================
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import Maintenances

# ==================================================
#                                  Fenêtre Principal - Configuration
# ==================================================
root = tk.Tk()                                                                                                    # Crée une instance Tk class
root.title("Principal")
root.resizable(False, False)                                                                                 # Fenêtre verrouillée

window_height = 150
window_width = 150

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

x_cordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))

root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))

def New_Maintenances():
    Maintenances.Maintenances_Contenu()

# ==================================================
#                                  Frames
# ==================================================

# --- Frame vertival droite ---
LeftFrame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="[+++]", font=('verdana', 8, ''), foreground="blue", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=0)
LeftFrame.place(x=5, y=5, width=123, height=200)

# Buttons
Bt4 = tk.Button(LeftFrame, width=16, text="checkbutton", font=('verdana', 8, ''), command=New_Maintenances)
Bt4.grid(row=4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

here code of Maintenance.py

```
# coding:utf-8
# version 3.x python

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.ttk import Button
from tkinter import Toplevel

def Maintenances_Contenu():

    Maintenance_Frame = tk.Toplevel()
    Maintenance_Frame.title('Toplevel')
    Maintenance_Frame.geometry("200x200+30+30")                                                                    # ("X Y+ 30+30")  561x305
    Maintenance_Frame.resizable(width=False, height=False)                                                         # Fenêtre verrouillée
    Maintenance_Frame.attributes("-toolwindow", 1)                                                                       # Supprime les boutons Réduire/Agrandir
    Maintenance_Frame.attributes("-topmost", 1)                                                                           # au priemier plan

    # ==============================================================
    #                                                            Cadres
    # ==============================================================


    FrameForm = Frame(Maintenance_Frame,  width=910)  #, relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1)
    FrameForm.grid(row=1, column=0)

    FrameRight = LabelFrame(FrameForm, text="[----]", width=550, height=304, relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1)
    FrameRight.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

    chkValue = tk.BooleanVar()
    chkValue.set(False)

    print("The checkbutton original value is {}".format(chkValue.get()))
    print("Etat d'origine --> Désactivé :", chkValue.get())
    print("\n")

    chkExample = Checkbutton(FrameRight, text='texte', var=chkValue)
    chkExample.place(x=2, y=102)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `chkValue` is garbage collected.  Save a reference of it as below:

```py
def Maintenances_Contenu():
    ...
    chkExample = tk.Checkbutton(FrameRight, text='texte', var=chkValue)
    chkExample.place(x=2, y=102)
    chkExample.var = chkValue  # save a reference
```